# How to validate bad input from a file stream?

Tags: c++, validation, file-io

I want to handle input validation in my such small program.

I have a file containing integer values separated by white spaces. But sometimes there's invalid values, for example letters or any other non-digit characters. So, I want to ignore those invalid values and push only the valid ints in a vector of integers.

Here is what I've tried out so far:

```
ifstream in("values");
if(!in)
    throw runtime_error("File \'values\' was not properly opened!");

vector<int> v;
int x = 0;
while( !(in >> x).eof() ){
    if( !in.fail() )
        v.push_back(x);
    else{
        cout << "Invalid input\n";
        in.clear();
        in.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

for(int val : v)
    cout << val << ", ";
```

The input file `values` contain this:

```
5 7 23 16 81 v 1474 119 21 29 5 88*
```

The output:

```
Invalid input
5, 7, 23, 16, 81,
```

Why `v` causes reading to stop? And why clearing the stream didn't put it back in a valid state so that it can read the remaining valid value?

What matters to me a lot is: If I use `std::cin` input stream in the very same program with the very same input values, I get it correctly and as I expected:

Input:

```
5
7
23
16
81
v
Invalid input
1474
119  
21
29
5
88*
Invalid input
Ctrl+D (eof)
```

Output:

```
5, 7, 23, 16, 81, 1474, 119, 21, 29, 5, 88,
```

Comment: You may also want to think about corner cases, like what should `1234foo` (no space) and `bar5678` result in? Should the numbers `1234` and `5678` be extracted or should both, or one, of them be rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file has everything on 1 line, so what do you think will happen when `v` is encountered and then `in.ignore()` is called to ignore everything up to the next `'\n'` (line break)? That's right, it will ignore the rest of the file!

When using `cin`, your input values are on separate lines, so calling `ignore()` with `'\n'` will ignore only the rest of the current line, leaving subsequent lines available for reading.

To solve your issue, try using `' '` (space) instead of `'\n'` (line break) when calling `ignore()` on your file stream:

```
in.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ' ');
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/jnnOPluvI)

Comment: Great! it works now just fine! Thank you again you've saved the day bro!